# How to prevent inplace modifications of a scipy sparse matrix?

Tags: python, scipy

For a scipy sparse matrix created as

```
from scipy import sparse
M = sparse.rand(100, 100, format='csr')
```

Is there a way to prevent it from being modified after construction ? That is, to disallow an operation such as `M[0, 0] = 1`.

My motivation is that I store `M` in an object `G` that has other attributes that depends on `M`. If `M` changes, then those attributes would have to be recomputed or `G` would be in an incoherent state. As `M` completely defines `G`, I'd rather prevent modification and force my users to instantiate another `G` from their new `M`. In code:

```
class G:
    def __init__(self, M):
        self.M = M
        self.d = M.sum(axis=0)

# Normal usage.
g = G(M)
print(g.M.toarray())
print(g.d)

# Modification out of my control that leads to an incoherent state.
M[0, 0] = 1
print(g.M.toarray())
print(g.d)
```

Comment: Is it more important to break the relationship between G and M or you require M[0,0]  =1 to be disallowed. You could always do self.M = M.copy()

Comment: I thought about `self.M = M.copy()`. The downsides are that (i) `M` is potentially large (like 10M x 10M), and (ii) `M` would need to be somehow encapsulated to prevent a user from modifying it (e.g., by doing `G.M[0, 0] = 1`).

Comment: It would actually be great if `M.copy()` was a copy-on-write.